Angular 18 component not being recognised/shown
I started making an Angular 18 app and I added my first component (using standalone components) and the app seems to not recognise my component because when I add it in my app.component.ts as a HTML tag and serve the app my component doesn't show.
Thanks!
Component to be shown as designed in the app

Not enough info, what's the error message? what does browser console say? Nothing can be deduced from what you are providing

If your app doesn't recognize that you're using the standalone component - without further information - you forgot to import it.
For example, if you wish to use the HeaderComponent in your app.component.ts you should explicitly import it in your component.
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet, HeaderComponent],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class AppComponent {

